# Code Collaborator file subscription for whole git repo

Tags: git, code-collaborator, github-codereviews

I'm trying to figure out what the right file pattern is to subscribe to any Code Collaborator reviews on a specific git repository.

So let's say I'm using the following git repo:

> ssh://username@host:port/path/to/repo/example.git

What is the file pattern I have to add to my Code Collaborator preferences?

I want to subscribe any code review within the repo submitted by any other user. I've tried all kinds of patterns, but nothing seems to be working for me.

More on file patterns can be found in the Code Collaborator manual [here](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/25414/#file-subscriptions) (there frankly isn't much information there, but that's all I really found).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's not currently a way to subscribe to code reviews for a particular Git repository.

While Code Collaborator does store information about the repository that changes have been uploaded from, that information is separate from the file path, so a file pattern won't be able to match on that information.

I've added a feature request for that in our user feedback forum here: 
http://feedback.codecollab.com/forums/4652-code-collaborator-features/suggestions/3138057-support-subscribing-to-reviews-from-particular-scm

In the meantime, if you're only working with a single git repository, then you can subscribe to *all* files with a pattern of "**" (without the quotes), which will give equivalent behavior.

Or, if you're working with different projects in different repositories, you could try to search for file paths unique to the project hosted in your Git repository.  For example:

src/java/main/com/example/yourproject/**

Comment: Thanks. Option #1 is unfortunately not applicable as we have a huge amount of projects. Option #2 seems to work, however it's not the best solution as that pattern might also apply to other repos (even other version control systems) that I'm interested in. Implementing the feature you posted above would be really important to actually achieve the mentioned goal.

Comment: That brings up other questions, though, like -- how do you uniquely identify a repository?

SVN does this right -- each repo has a unique GUID.   Perforce does not have any sort of GUID.  We sortof fake it with Git and use the "first commit" (a commit with no parents) for a GUID for a repo.  But -- did you know you can merge multiple unrelated repos together, resulting in multiple "first commits"?  Then we just pick one.  (The earliest, I think?)   And that's only 3 of the many SCMs we support.  :)